# How to automate daily copying files that are being stored in the daily folder using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have a such scenario, in a data lake Gen2 files being generated daily and stored in a folder structure like for example yyyy/mm/dd, my task is picked all all the files from previous day from daily folder merge them and move to another location in a data lake Gen2

What would be the right approach? can I use exclusively only ADF or has to be a combination with some sort of controlling table that would have values from last day process, like for example if there was a problem and  files need to be processed from 3 days ago instead of yesterday, how do I know? how to keep track and what would be the appraoch to automate such process, I imagine it is scenario that been developed multiple times, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use dynamic content to get the yesterday's day using which you will be able to read all the files inside the folder structure `yyyy/MM/dd`.

```
@formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1))
```

[image]

- You can use the dynamically generated folder structure as wildcard path to read all the files in required folder.

```
source/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'dd')}
```

[image]

- In the sink, you can select your destination folder, give copy behavior as `Merge Files` (give required filename in sink dataset else random name will be generated).

[image]

- To automate this process daily, you can use `schedule trigger` as shown below. Navigate to `Add trigger -> New/Edit -> Choose new trigger`. You can select the intervals at which you want to run this pipeline (one day). and create the trigger.

[image]

- Publish the pipeline and this will trigger the pipeline daily, merging files from yesterday's folder to create a new merged file in destination. The following is pipeline JSON for reference:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "yesterdays date",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "wildcardFolderPath": {
                                "value": "source/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'dd')}",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "wildcardFileName": "*.csv",
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
                            "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "src",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "dest",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "yesterdays date",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "yesterday",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "yesterday": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that will get me started

Comment: Would it be possible to pass source path into the destination path? I have built path from the Set Variable activity and it worked fine, now I would like to  store retrieved files  in the same path that was in the source just different root, example I sourced from: source1/2023/01/01, and want to store it in dest1/2023/01/01, but mapping destination does not allow me to pass the variable unless I am doing something wrong

Comment: Use this dynamic content in the sink dataset's folder path `destination/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(variables('yesterday'),'dd')}` and it should work

Comment: Saideep, thanks for your help, but this dynamic content cannot be passed into dataflow dataset from pipeline, it does not work

Comment: I don't think so, you can open a new question about this issue about what's not working

Comment: Just did but it is a different question, relates to passing value from a pipeline to data flow dataset.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75591201/how-to-pass-variable-content-from-a-pipeline-to-a-dataset-path-inside-of-a-data