# How to pass variable content from a Pipeline to a dataset path inside of a Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that sets variable for the purpose of building dynamic data path that gets passed into a dataset within a pipeline, that works fine thanks to help on this site, but there is another issue when I tried to pass that variable into a data flow and use it as source for building a dataset within a dataflow it does not work, pipeline expression builder does not see it, it sees only parameters created locally from the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you create a parameter for dataset and use that dataset in dataflow, it is not showing within the dataflow itself. But when you finish building the dataflow and use this dataflow inside the pipeline in `dataflow` activity.
- Lets say I have the following dataset, where I have created a parameter called `req_path`.

[image]

- This parameter does not show up when I use it in either source or sink of the dataflow:

[image]

- However, when I complete building the dataflow and use it in pipeline, you will be prompted to enter the value for `req_path` parameter.

[image]

- So, there is no need to pass the path value to dataflow and instead pass it directly to dataset (when dataset is used in dataflow transformation).