# How to pass pipeline variable into dataflow source dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline variable that contains the string "customers.txt"
I want to pass it into my dataflow's source dataset's file path
[dataflow's source dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueLN5.png)

However, it is not showing up. How do I go about doing this?

This is my dataflow's settings:

[dataflow settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn7ZZ.png)
[dataflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV5Jv.png)

I have tried following this as well [How to pass variable content from a Pipeline to a dataset path inside of a Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75591201/how-to-pass-variable-content-from-a-pipeline-to-a-dataset-path-inside-of-a-data?rq=2)

Comment: Did you tried debug the pipeline? any error you are facing?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula Yup I did. My pipeline works fine but my dataflow errors out. I have included snapshot of the error i am getting in my dataflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your approach. Your dataflow will execute fine when you debug it through pipeline.

I did the same and I got the expected results.

[image]

Here my source file name is `mycsv2.csv` which I have stored it in a variable and passed it using dataset parameters. I have transformed the data from this file to a target file named `target1.csv`.

**Result:**

[image]

**If you want to check the data preview in the dataflow debug**, you need to pass value for the dataset parameter in the dataflow.

When you click on refresh in the data preview of the source, it asks the value for the parameter and you need to give your file name (which you want to check the preview for) like below.

[image]

Click on save and now you can see the data preview. Now your **import projection** also works fine in the source. This value is only for the dataflow debug.

[image]

**So, if you want check data preview for further transformations, first you need to provide a static value for the dynamic parameters in the source data preview. For the next transformations, it will give the data preview for the above data.**

But while debugging the pipeline, it will take the value for the parameter from the pipeline.

Comment: Hello Rakesh, I found out my issue was that in my dataflow, I have a select activity that i use to select the columns i want to map to my sink data set. In my select activity i have mappings under the input column. These mappings are causing the error: "Input column in mapping cannot be found for my select activity." 
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: As your primary ask is about passing parameters, it's better to raise a new ask about this with detailed steps that you have followed so that I can try from my end.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I've raised a new ask! Thanks for the help